# Haskell: Ошибка синтаксиса, которую я не могу понять

Tags: haskell

Решаю задачу по функциональному программированию, и мне нужно рассчитать сложный процент рекурсивно. Вот мой код, логично он описан более-менее правильно (хотя чувствую, что в функции которая будет рекурситься есть костыль):

```hs
countInterest :: (Integer, Float, Integer) -> (Float)
countInterest (period,interest,sum) = (result) where 
  result=sum+interest/30
  timePeriod=period-1
  if period == 0
    then return result
  else countInterest (timePeriod,interest,result)


main=do
  putStrLn "Enter start sum:"
  inputSum <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter interest amount by one period:"
  inputInterest <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter period amount:"
  inputPeriod <- getLine
  let startSum=(read inputSum :: Int)
  let interestByPeriod=(read inputInterest :: Int)
  let periodAmount=(read inputPeriod :: Int)
  let periodCounting=countInterest(periodAmount,interestByPeriod,0)
  print(periodCounting)
  let result = startSum*(1+periodCounting)^366
  print("Result ", result)
```

Но я не могу его запустить, потому что мне постоянно выдаёт ошибку (не одну и ту же; от изменений, которые я делаю меняется и ошибка). На данный момент ругается на название функции `main` error message: `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)`

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения синтаксиса, ошибка здесь

```hs
countInterest (period,interest,sum) =
  if period == 0
    then result
    else countInterest (timePeriod,interest,result)
  where
    result=sum+interest/30
    timePeriod=period-1
```

Конструкция if/then это выражение, которое в зависимости от условия, принимает одно из двух значений. Как раз то, что вам нужно.
Не особо вдаваясь в подробности, замечу, что `return` здесь не нужен, а точнее, его здесь быть не должно. Это не синтаксическая ошибка, потому, что `return` – это не оператор, а функция (ох уж эти коварные хаскеллисты), но в этом месте программы применения не имеет.

В остальном же у вас несколько ошибок типов, которые в Haskell автоматически не приводятся, и их нужно указывать правильно (или не указывать вовсе: в большинстве случаев компилятор сможет вывести типы самостоятельно).

```hs
countInterest :: (Integer, Float, Float) -> (Float)
countInterest (period,interest,sum) =
  if period == 0
    then result
    else countInterest (timePeriod,interest,result)
  where
    result=sum+interest/30
    timePeriod=period-1

main=do
  putStrLn "Enter start sum:"
  inputSum <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter interest amount by one period:"
  inputInterest <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter period amount:"
  inputPeriod <- getLine
  let startSum=(read inputSum :: Float)
  let interestByPeriod=(read inputInterest :: Float)
  let periodAmount=(read inputPeriod :: Integer)
  let periodCounting=countInterest(periodAmount,interestByPeriod,0)
  print(periodCounting)
  let result = startSum*(1+periodCounting)^366
  print("Result ", result)
```

Ну и последнюю строку вы, наверное, захотите записать иначе

```hs
  putStrLn ("Result " ++ show result)
```

(По поводу стиля кода и правильности работы алгоритма – без комментариев)